# C++ vscode error launch: program <program_path> does not exist

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm purely new to C++ and just started learning. I'm using VSCode 1.76.2.

I have installed `gcc` as told in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw and added the installation path to `PATH` and up to this point it's OK.

The issue is when I try to run Debug in VSCode, it get the following error:

> lunch: "program": "c:/Users/Saeed/Desktop/cpp-projects/build/Debug/outDebug" does not exist

What I do is I only installed the C++ extension suggested by VSCode.

I can compile my Hello World app to `.exe` and run it with `ctrl+shift+b`, but I cannot start debugging or even Run Without Debugging due to this error.

I googled this issue and tried to do what other links of StackOverFlow and other websites suggest but none of them solved my issue.

Comment: Did "installed the C++ extension" include editing the configuration in the json-files? If not, you have to start there. (As an aside - if you don't particularly like json-files, the full Visual Studio Community comes preconfigured and with all extensions included. Just saying).

Comment: @BoP yes I installed https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools. But I'm not sure about the extension for `json` files and which one to install. Is the issue related to `json`?

Comment: I don't use VSCode myself, but see numerous questions about it not working as expected. Almost always this is because some configuration is missning.